# When incrementing pointer to struct array on powerPC sizeof does not work as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I am writing code for a custom embedded platform that runs a powerPC and uses the powerpc-eabi-gcc compiler.

My code that causes me issues is the following:

Structs are declared as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    ..lots of floats
} AGA8_Inputs;
```

Arrays are declared:

```
AGA8_Inputs* AGA8InputsArray;
int* calcStepArray;

void init(){
    AGA8InputsArray = malloc(streamNumbers*sizeof(AGA8_Inputs));
    calcStepArray = malloc(streamNumbers*sizeof(int));
    memset(AGA8InputsArray, 0, streamNumbers*sizeof(AGA8_Inputs));
    memset(calcStepArray, 0, streamNumbers*sizeof(int));
```

Issue occurs here when streamNumber is >= 1:

```
int FlowCalculation(int streamNumber)
{
    // Perform AGA8 calculations
    AGA8_Inputs *AGA8Inputs = (AGA8InputsArray + sizeof(AGA8_Inputs) * streamNumber);   
    int *calcStep = calcStepArray + sizeof(AGA8_Outputs) * streamNumber;
```

Get a data access violation when I access AGA8_Inputs->element or *calcStep == 0

Now the problem goes away when i do the following:

```
AGA8_Inputs *AGA8Inputs = AGA8InputsArray;
int *calcStep = calcStepArray;
AGA8Inputs += streamNumber;
calcStep += streamNumber;
```

Shouldn't sizeof(AGA8_Inputs)*streamNumber do the exact same thing as += streamNumber? Or is this a strange quirk of the PowerPC compiler?

Comment: I don't follow what the issue is. I'm using two variables "Streamnumbers" and "Streamnumber".

Comment: Or if you insist on multiplying it should be `(char*)AGA8InputsArray + sizeof(AGA8_Inputs) * streamNumber`

Comment: I see so my previous example would only be correct if I was using a char pointer. I misunderstood when the compiler treated my arithmetic as pointer arithmetic or normal maths.

Comment: Yeah it seems kind of obvious now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also thanks for the pointer (lol) about calloc. I had never heard of it before (I don't write C very often).

Comment: OK, will change my comments into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
AGA8_Inputs *AGA8Inputs = (AGA8InputsArray + sizeof(AGA8_Inputs) * streamNumber);
```

should be:

```
AGA8_Inputs *AGA8Inputs = (AGA8InputsArray + streamNumber);
```

The `AGA8InputsArray` is a pointer, so adding an integer to it performs pointer arithmetic.  Adding `1` to a pointer makes the pointer point to the next object of its type, and so on.

The `calcStep` line has a similar fix.

NB. The `calloc` function can be used instead of `malloc` followed by `memset`.